# send php variable data in mail using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, html-email

Hello I am pretty new to codeigniter. This may seems to be the simple question. But i don't know how to resolve it.

In my application i have to send the data to the user. That data will include the php variable now how can i send those variables as message.

Here is my code

The configuration settings to email

```
$config = Array(        
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'user@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '******',
        'smtp_timeout' => '4',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );

        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

The email code is

```
$phpVariable="some data";       

    $message="<html><body><span>This is php data $phpVariable</span></body></html>";

 $this->email->from('review@findacarehome.com','Review for Find a care home');
        $this->email->to('anotheruser@gmail.com');
        $this->email->Subject('Subject');
        $this->email->message($message);

        $this->email->send();
```

Please help me i am not getting error i'm simply getting the mail without php data

Comment: doesn't it works ? what's the problem ??

Comment: @egig am getting the mail perfectly but i am not getting the php varable data in it

Comment: What do you see in the mail?

Comment: "This is php data" this is what i'm getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using {} around the variable, should work.

```
$message="<html><body><span>This is php data {$phpVariable}</span></body></html>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$message="<html><body><span>This is php data " . $phpVariable . "</span></body></html>";
```